# Maven como definir a versão do JDK?

Tags: java, maven

**Problema:**

Quando crio um projeto `maven` o projeto sempre ficava com a versão `JDK 1.5`, se alterar na IDE a versão do JDK ao fazer um `Maven > Project Update` ele volta para `JDK 1.5`.

O arquivo `setting.xml` é o lugar onde defino a versão de todos os projetos maven? Se não onde faço para todos os novos projetos sempre utilizem a versão `JDK 1.7` por exemplo.

---

**Observação:** encontrei uma forma de resolver o problema usando o arquivo `pom.xml`.

Código:

```
<!-- CONFIGURAR VERSÃO DO JAVA PARA 1.7 -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**Vantagem e Desvantagem**

Entendo que a *vantagem* deste código é que cada projeto Maven pode trabalhar com uma versão especificado Java. A *desvantagem* desse código é para cada novo projeto tenho que alterar o `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Sua solução está correta, isto é, usar a configuração do *Maven Compiler Plugin* para especificar a versão do Java do projeto.

## Especificando a *instalação* do Java

Além da versão, é possível especificar qual **executável** ou instalação será usada para compilação com a tag `<executable>`.

Exemplo:

```xml
<!-- CONFIGURAR VERSÃO DO JAVA PARA 1.7 -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Veja a [documentação aqui](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html).

## Especificar o Java é uma boa prática

Esse tipo de configuração é importante pois existem casos onde um código compilado com uma versão posterior do Java, mesmo em modo de compatibilidade, não roda numa versão anterior. Não acredita?

Um exemplo simples é o construtor da classe `BigDecimal` que recebe um inteiro. Ele foi adicionado no Java 5, mas é compilado sem problemas em compatibilidade para Java 1.4. Obviamente, ao executar o código ocorre um erro em tempo de execução, só não me lembro exatamente qual a classe da exceção.

## Não precisa se repetir

Quanto à desvantagem de ter que configurar para cada novo projeto, crie um [*parent pom*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) em um projeto vazio (com exceção do pom) e use a herança para reaproveitar essa configuração em todos os seus projetos.

Veja como especificar o pai:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.minhaempresa</groupId>
    <artifactId>meu-pom-principal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

Isso nos dá um tremendo ganho de produtividade!

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, pensei que teria uma forma universal e que o arquivo `setting.xml` existi-se para isso. Fico feliz em saber que outros programadores utilizam esse método e que ter uma forma de usar o mesmo `pom.xml` para N projetos.

Answer (score 2):

Eduardo, a solução é essa mesma, configurar o plugin de compilação para versão do Java desejada.

```
<!-- CONFIGURAR VERSÃO DO JAVA PARA 1.7 -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note que o Maven é independente da IDE, portanto qualquer configuração deve ser feita no `pom.xml`. E no Eclipse, quando você faz um `Maven > Project Update` o efeito é justamente ao contrário. Ele atualiza as configurações do projeto com base no `pom.xml`.

Agora, se você tem muitos projetos e todos eles utilizam o Maven, uma boa prática é ter *parent* para todos eles, onde você pode definir tudo que é comum para  todos os projeto. Você pode ler mais sobre projetos *parent* [aqui](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance). No caso de versão do Java, o `pom.xml` do seu *parent* ficaria assim:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    <plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel Cartagena vou ler sobre projetos parent.