# Configuração do maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Criei um projeto `Maven` (OBS: é a primeira vez que estou mexendo nessa tecnologia), mas ele está dando esse erro. Esse `plugin` que a mensagem está falando eu preciso instalá-lo? Como faço?

Outra coisa, quando vou nas `propriedades do projeto >> Project faces` e clico em `dynamic web module 3.1` ele pede a versão do `java 1.7`. Está certo isso? A meu ver deveria apontar pra o `Java 1.8`, já que as tecnologias que estou usando são mais atuais.

Minha máquia está com essas configurações:
- Maven 3.3
- JDK 1.8
- Tomcat 8.0.23

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**EDIÇÃO:** este é meu `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hellemos</groupId>
    <artifactId>Financeiro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

Comment: Acho que você poderia separar sua dúvida em duas publicações. Ou não, caso esse tópico lhe resolva a segunda: [Maven como definir a versão do JDK?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6391/3117)

Comment: Eu já tinha feito essa configuração, e não está dando certo também.

Comment: Duas coisas: Primeiro, você está executando o maven em algum local com conexão a internet para que o maven baixe <strike>a internet toda</strike> as dependências dos plugins? Segundo, poste o seu `pom.xml`.

Comment: Sim, estou com conexão com a internet.

Comment: Utilize o link de [edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/67398/edit) na sua pergunta para incluir o arquivo `pom.xml`, nos comentários fica difícil de visualizar :)

Comment: Obrigado @re22 =) era isso que estava procurando rs

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o maven por linha de comando?

mvn clean install deverá rodar as fases clean e install de seu projeto, apenas abra o prompt, vá até a pasta onde está o seu pom.xml e rode este comando> mvn clean intall

Tive experiências ruins com plugins do Maven, principalmente no Eclipse, no IntelliJ tudo sempre funcionou pra mim.

Comment: Nesse video ensina direitinho como configurar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M6h8PrZN00

Comment: Deu certo \o/ Era a configuração do maven que eu ainda não tinha feito, por isso estava dando errado. Obrigado @LucasEduardo

Comment: @user25945 posta a resposta para poder ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: ou você tambem @LucasEduardo

Comment: no vídeo que @LucasEduardo postou já está com a resposta Reginaldo ^^